# How do I bind a textbox to a Model parameter in a Strongly Typed View in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, forms, model, strongly-typed-view

The only way I've seen this done in the tutorials I've looked at, they say to create a new .ascx and choose the option "create" for View Content.

I want to be able to customize mine more with specific ID's... So, if I have a Customer that has data: `string FirstName`, `string LastName`, `string Address`. How can I bind my textboxes so that when the form is submitted, the textbox values get used as FirstName/LastName/Address?

Here's my form:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MySite.Models.Entities.EntityFramework.Customer>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("myform_CustFirstName") %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("myform_CustLastName") %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("myform_CustAddr") %>

    <input type="submit" value="Add Customer" />
<% } %>
```

What do I need to do to bind each to the correct Model parameter?
I tried this:

```
<% Model.FirstName = Html.TextBox("myform_CustFirstName") %>
```

and that gave me an error...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be looking at writing your own Model Binder for that ... just google it a bit and you will find various resources on writing your own model binder....

Here you find an [example](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/09/08/CustomModelBinderMoreUIValidationASPNETMVC.aspx)